# Using a shared access signature (SAS URI) for Azure Tables from Delphi

Tags: delphi, azure-table-storage

I am using Delphi and trying to access an Azure Table, and I can successfully connecting using my account name and account key, something like this:

```
connInfo := TAzureConnectionInfo.Create( nil );
connInfo.AccountName := STORAGE_ACCOUNT;
connInfo.AccountKey := STORAGE_API_KEY;
tables := TAzureTableService.Create( connInfo );
```

However, I want to access the tables using a shared access signature instead, so that I will not have to expose and/or hardcode the my storage api key, as this gives complete access to the storage account.

So, how can I specify that I want to use the generated SAS URI instead of using my account key?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code using [`TAzureConnectionInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.Cloud.AzureAPI.TAzureConnectionInfo), I think you were using Delphi via embarcadero RAD Studio. I'm not familiar with Delphi and RAD Studio. However, per my experience, if Azure service does not support and offer a SDK directly for a programming language like Delphi, the best way is using Azure REST APIs with [HttpClient](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient) supported by this language.

So you can refer to the offical REST API reference for [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services) to generate a SAS token for using [Table Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api).

Meanwhile, there is an offical code sample [Getting Started with Shared Access Signatures (SAS)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/storage-dotnet-sas-getting-started/) in C# if you are familiar with C#.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.  There are plenty of classes in Delphi to support Acure development, and I have created a SAS token.  What I fail do find out is how to apply that token to the classes that come with Delphi/C++ Builder.  I will look at the C# examples, to see if that gives me some ideas.  I can always process the JSON myself, but it would be a lot easier to rely on the classes in Delphi, which are otherwise a pleasure to use.